# How can I assign an arraylist that i got from a method into another arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
    private List<Product> itemList;

    public List<Product> getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }
```

And then try to recieve like this...

```
 public void doMySearch (String query){
    System.out.println("bikaMiden");
    List<Product> searchResult = new ArrayList<Product>();
    List<Product> result = new ArrayList<Product>();
    System.out.println("bikagamwwwwwwwww");
    result= adapter.getItemList();
    System.out.println("bikaMIA");
    for (Product product : result) {
        System.out.println("bika");
        if (product.getProductName().contains(query)) {

            searchResult.add(product);
            System.out.println("vrika" + product);
            }
        }

    adapter.setItemList(searchResult);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have tried 50 different aproaches it always crashes at the assign to the result command please if u know help me...

```
    02-27 21:51:58.847: D/AndroidRuntime(3194): Shutting down VM
02-27 21:51:58.857: W/dalvikvm(3194): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.ac.kent.jhp20.shopper/uk.ac.kent.jhp20.shopper.ProductListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at uk.ac.kent.jhp20.shopper.ProductListActivity.doMySearch(ProductListActivity.java:139)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at uk.ac.kent.jhp20.shopper.ProductListActivity.onCreate(ProductListActivity.java:115)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     ... 11 more
02-27 21:57:00.157: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 8% free 2778K/2988K, paused 43ms, total 47ms
02-27 21:57:00.177: I/dalvikvm-heap(3221): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.939MB for 1127536-byte allocation
02-27 21:57:00.217: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3876K/4092K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
02-27 21:57:00.408: D/libEGL(3221): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
02-27 21:57:00.418: D/(3221): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1bdc30, tid 3221
02-27 21:57:00.437: D/libEGL(3221): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
02-27 21:57:00.448: D/libEGL(3221): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
02-27 21:57:00.489: W/EGL_emulation(3221): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-27 21:57:00.489: D/OpenGLRenderer(3221): Enabling debug mode 0
02-27 21:57:00.538: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 5% free 4259K/4444K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
02-27 21:57:00.627: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 4614K/4796K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
02-27 21:57:00.707: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4969K/5148K, paused 21ms, total 22ms
02-27 21:57:00.797: I/Choreographer(3221): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

here is the logcat...please help..I am building an android project and i am really new at this sorry if the question is stupid..
Update The adapter isn't null my oncreate method is here the project is fairly huge so i had to pick  some parts...

```
private ProductListAdapter adapter;
private ListViewLoader loader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get the category form the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    /*
     *  To here
     */
    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        System.out.println("bika");

        /*
         *  because you refer to it here
         */
        doMySearch(query);

        System.out.println("ti paixtike edw malakako?");
    }
    else
    {
        categoryId = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.SELECTED_CATEGORY, 1);

        /*
         *  Move this
         *
        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
         *
         */

        loader = new ListViewLoader(adapter, categoryId);
        loader.execute(String.format(MainActivity.WEBSERVER_GETLIST, categoryId));
    }

    setupActionBar();
}
```

Comment: Without an error log will be a litlle dificult to help, can you add your logcat?

Comment: Try checking for result being null before you iterate through it.

Comment: 02-27 21:51:58.847: D/AndroidRuntime(3194): Shutting down VM
02-27 21:51:58.857: W/dalvikvm(3194): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.ac.kent.jhp20.shopper/uk.ac.kent.jhp20.shopper.ProductListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 21:51:58.897: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)

Comment: i had to cut it becaus ut was too long..sorry :/ it always crashes at this command: result= adapter.getItemList();

Comment: You can edit the question and put the logcat as a code block.

Comment: it seems to me that your adapter is null, when are you calling the doMySearch() method? can you share more code?

Comment: I've updated the question the adapter isn't null..

Comment: See my edit to the `onCreate`.  You're adapter was not set up when you called `doMySearch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter is null and because of that the getItemList() could not be called! This results in a NullPointerException.

Check that the adapter is not null.

Comment: could you show more details of the OnCreate Method?

Comment: I think that the adapter is null, did you check with debug? Because you set the adapter only on the else path. And you call the *doMySearch()* method only on the if path.

Comment: u might be right...everytime a new activity is created even though the adapter is a global variable it's recreated right?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to keep it just make it static, but also then could go first to the if path.

Comment: The issue is way more complicated than i what i first though unfortunatelly..yes the adapter was null but it seems to me that when i recreate the adaptor it hasn't stored the previous itemList as I expected...so even though the command works the arraylist is still a null...

Comment: Ok I finally resolved the issue by using android:launchMode="singleTop". I checked and adapter is NOT null and all other variables are there properly...but the original issue still remains...result=adapter.getItemList(); gives me back a null :/ can u help?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see where your null might be but as Edwin T has already pointed out it's probably the adaptor object. However I recommend in this case put a null check on your adaptor and on your item result.

So something like this:

```
public void doMySearch(String query){

    if (adapter != null) {
        List<Product> searchResult = new ArrayList<Product>();
        List<Product> result = new ArrayList<Product>();

        result = adapter.getItemList();

        if (result != null) {
            for (Product product : result) {

                if (product.getProductName().contains(query)) {

                    searchResult.add(product);
                }
            }

            adapter.setItemList(searchResult);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```